# how to change textarea data to text file in CodeIgniter and send it via mail

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my current project, for the career section if someone applies for the job I need to send the applicants data(name, email, contact, resume, cover-letter) to admin mail. I want to change the cover-letter textarea data to text file and then only send as mail. How should I do it in CodeIgniter or just using php? Searched for the related but not found.

Thanks for any help/suggestions.

my current code after going through the @Iraklis answer.

controller

```
function form_submit(){
  $resume = $_FILES['field_name']['tmp_name'];
  $name = $this->input->post('name');
  $coverletter = $this->input->post('cover');
  $file_name = 'resume.txt';
  $data = file_put_contents($file_name, $coverletter);
 $this->load->library('email');
 $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
 $config['validate'] = TRUE;
 $this->email->initialize($config);
$this->email->from('some@example.com', 'xxx Technologies');
 $this->email->to($form->admin_email); 
                                $this->email->subject('Carrere');

$message = 'Name '.$name;
$message .='resume '.$data;
$this->email->message($message);

                                $this->email->send();
}
```

Now form the mail I receive i get resume as 29. What am i doing wrong??

and when i use $this->email->attach() for file attachment. I dont get any message. the mail will be blank.Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**To save your textarea "data" to file you can use the following method.**

```
 //Your File name for Storage of the required Field Data
 $file = 'FILE_NAME.txt';

 //Open file in Overwrite Mode
 $fh = fopen($file,'w+');

 //Write the content of required field in to the file
 fwrite($fh,$this->input->post('YOUR_CUSTOM_FIELD'));
 fclose($fh);
```

**Finally you can use the CI Email Class to attach the file**

```
 $this->email->attach($file);
```

Answer (score 4):

As for the solution of $this->email->attach() I found that instead of just

$this->email->attach()

it should actually be

$this->email->attach($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'path_to_file'.$file)

i.e. Path to the file should also be given.

Answer (score 0):

For sending emails, (including attachments), CI has a an Email class that you can use : http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html

For saving the textarea "data" to a text file you have a number of options. One is the following:

```
$cvdata = $this->input->post('cvdata');

// do what you want with $cvdata

$file_name = 'coverletter.txt';
file_put_contents($file, $cvdata);
```

Comment: @ Iraklis I only got 29 as resume.What's wrong?? Can't seem to find it.